# Will the hair of my Yorkie Terrier growth so long?

Tags: dogs, grooming

My mom got a new puppy Yorkie Terrier. I went to google and searched for `Yorkie Terrier` and found these pictures

[image]

Mine looks like the one on the left but he's just one month old.

I'm wondering if all Yorkies will have the same hair as adults or if I have to take special care to make it look like the second one. Or are they all different kinds of Yorkies?

Are there some tips to improve his hair for him to look like the middle one? I don't want to attempt anything I am not sure about in case I provide bad care and he ends up looking like the one on the right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll make some general observations that might apply if your dog is pure-bred. The long-haired dogs you see at dog shows always look impeccably groomed, with long, flowing fur. That is because they are brushed every day, often multiple times per day. Long fur tends to tangle easily and/or break as a dog runs around, rolls around, or simply lies down, and if the tangles are not removed promptly they begin to form mats. Dogs with fur that touches the ground may have that fur tied up and protected when the dog goes outside. In other words, keeping that coat in show-quality condition is a very time consuming and arduous commitment. It also means that the dogs may not be able to run and play freely.

This is why you will rarely see dogs with long perfect coats in everyday life. Many people have their dogs clipped periodically because shorter hair is much easier to brush and keep tangle free. Matted fur is painful for the dog, and must be removed. It is likely that the dog on the right was clipped (received a haircut).

I have a [Bearded Collie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bearded_Collie) that I keep in full coat (I never have her fur shortened by clipping). But she does not look nearly as good as a Beardie in a dog show. I do thoroughly brush her twice a week, but that is not enough to keep her coat completely mat free. When I cut mats out, the coat loses that overall smooth look. And the day after I brush, the fur get tousled and begins to tangle, so that perfectly groomed, flowing look is gone.

So to answer your question, if your puppy is a pure-bred Yorkie, it is possible to have him look like the dog in the middle if you are willing to put in the time and effort. You can also have them groomed, leaving the coat longer than the dog on the right as a compromise: He will be easier to keep in good coat condition and look more like the dog in the middle than the one on the right.

Answer (score 1):

All Yorkies look like the one on the left as a puppy unless they are mixed or what some call a party-Yorkie. They begin to change color around 6-8 weeks. Not all Yorkies are able to look like the one in the middle no matter how much work you put into him/her.  If they aren't bred from good quality dogs then they could have somewhat rough and course wirey hair. That hair won't grow but a maximum of 3 inches or so. Some good silky haired Yorkies won't grow to the floor either. Just like in humans, it depends on genetics and hair care but like I just said, some hair just doesn't grow long no matter what you do to it.